# Storing State in React JS not working as excepted

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks, state

what i am creating here is a sorter with 3 inputs like shown here . This sorter will get some data from a table. Now i'm setting state with initSelect and i'm passing it the fields array but when i console.log(select) it gives me the object shown in the image which is incorrect from the behaviours i want **{sorterParam1: 'Date', sorterParam2: '', sorterParam3: ''}**
The first input has to have a default value of 'Date' always , but it can change to other values in the dropdown list like name , username ect . When i console log the select state it is messed up as it's always selecting the last one on the fields array , how can i change the initSelects function to correctly build the object i want.

[image]

[image]

Also the tricky thing which i can't seem to do is , if this Date value is selcted , in the second input, the date value should not be there. And if in the second input we select another value like Earth , Earth and Date should not be in the 3rd input and so on. So basically it means filtering out values . I need serious help as this is for the company i work on

**Excepted Behaviour:** Dynamically update value every time i select one input element like
{sorterParam1: 'Date', sorterParam2: '', sorterParam3: ''}
When selectin 'Date' for example , it shouldn't not be included in the dropdownlist on sorterParam2, sorterParam3.

```js
/*eslint-disable*/
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { GridSortModel } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import SorterField from './SorterField';
const initSelects = (fields) => {
  let object = {};

  fields.map((item) => {
    console.log(item, 'item');
    object = {
      ...item,
      [item.name]: item.defaultValue ? item.defaultValue : '',
    };
  });

  return object;
};

const Sorter = ({ menuItemsValue, setSortData }: SortProps) => {
  const fields: SorterProps[] = [
    {
      name: 'sorterParam1',
      title: 'Sort by',
      optional: false,
      defaultValue: 'Date',
    },
    {
      name: 'sorterParam2',
      title: 'Then by',
      optional: true,
    },
    {
      name: 'sorterParam3',
      title: 'Then by',
      optional: true,
    },
  ];
  const [select, setSelect] = useState<any>(() => initSelects(fields));

  const getMenuItems = useMemo(() => {
    return menuItemsValue.filter((item) => select.sorterParam1 !== item);
  }, [menuItemsValue, select]);

  const handleSelectChange = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    console.log(111, name, value);
    setSelect({ ...select, [name]: value });
    setSortData(sortOptions);
  };

  const handleClearAllInputs = () => {
    setSelect({
      sorterParam1: '',
      sorterParam2: '',
      sorterParam3: '',
    });
  };

  const handleConfirm = () => {};
  return (
    <TextField
      label="Advanced Sorting"
      className={styles.sorter__inputs}
      id="sorter-parameter-1"
      variant="standard"
      InputProps={{
        disableUnderline: true,
      }}
      select
      SelectProps={{
        IconComponent: (props) => <NewIcon {...props} />,
      }}
      sx={{
        fontSize: '12px',
        width: '100%',
        '& .MuiInputBase-input:focus': {
          backgroundColor: 'transparent !important',
        },
        '& .MuiInputLabel-root': {
          color: '#9E9E9E',
        },
        '& .MuiTextField-root': {
          fontSize: '13px',
        },
        '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
        },
      }}
    >
      {fields.map((option, index) => (
        <SorterField
          key={option.name}
          menuItemsValue={getMenuItems}
          name={option.name}
          option={option}
          count={fields.length}
          handleChange={handleSelectChange}
          index={index + 1} // setData={setData}
        />
      ))}
      <div className={styles.sorter__inputControllers}>
        <Button
          className={styles.sorter__clearAllInput}
          onClick={() => handleClearAllInputs()}
        >
          Clear All
        </Button>
        <Button
          onClick={() => handleConfirm()}
          className={styles.sorter__confirmInput}
        >
          Confirm
        </Button>
      </div>
    </TextField>
  );
};

export default Sorter;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This is the SorterField Component code if that might be helpful

```js
/*eslint-disable*/
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import { MenuItem } from '@mui/material';

import { SorterProps } from '../../types/Sorter';

import { ReactComponent as SorterLine } from '../../assets/img/sortLine.svg';
import styles from '../../assets/components/Sorter/sorter.module.scss';

type SorterFieldProps = {
  menuItemsValue: string[];
  option: SorterProps;
  count: number;
  name: string;
  handleChange: (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
  ) => void;
  index: number;
};

function SorterField({
  option,
  count,
  menuItemsValue,
  handleChange,
  index,
}: SorterFieldProps) {

  const handleSorting = () => {};

  return (
    <div className={styles.sorter__container}>
      <div className={styles.sorter__header}>
        <p className={styles.sorter__label}>
          {option.title}{' '}
          {option.optional && (
            <sup className={styles.sorter__optional}>*Optional</sup>
          )}
        </p>

        <div className={styles.sorter__numbers__container}>
          {Array.from({ length: count }, (_, i) => i + 1).map((number) => (
            <>
              {number === index ? (
                <>
                  <span className={styles.sorter__number}>{index}</span>
                </>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <span className={styles.sorter__numbers}>{number}</span>
                </>
              )}
            </>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.sorter__inputs}>
        <TextField
          className={[styles.sorter__input, styles.sorter__field__input].join(
            ' '
          )}
          variant="outlined"
          label="Select"
          select
          SelectProps={{
            IconComponent: () => <NewIcon />,
          }}
          value={option.defaultValue}
          onChange={handleChange}
          name={option.title}
          size="small"
        >
          {menuItemsValue.map((title, idx) => (
            <MenuItem key={idx} value={title}>
              {title}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>

        <div onClick={handleSorting} className={styles.sorter__sortOrder}>
          <div className={styles.sorter__sortOrder__alphabetical}>
            <span>A</span>
            <span>Z</span>
          </div>

          <div className={styles.sorter__sortOrder__sortLine}>
            <SorterLine />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SorterField;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're re-assigning a value to `object` in each iteration of `fields.map()`. Did you mean to add to it instead? Should `object` be an array?

Comment: i'm getting the fields which is an array that jas 3 objects inside. And i want to get the name of each object as i'm using indexes with the [] braces and trying to build this object = {sorterParam1: '', sorterParam2: '', sorterParam3: ''} so i can store them on a single state

Comment: FYI if you move the `fields` declaration out of your component, you can omit it as a dependency in any hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're re-assigning a value to `object` in each iteration of `fields.map()`.

If you want to build `object` as a map of field item `name` to `defaultValue` (or blank string), use this instead...

```js
return Object.fromEntries(
  fields.map(({ name, defaultValue }) => [name, defaultValue ?? ""])
);
```

See [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

Also, **move the `fields` declaration outside your component**. It's static content so can be omitted from being declared every render and from any hook dependencies.

---

You could also use [`fields.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which is basically the same thing

```js
return fields.reduce(
  (obj, { name, defaultValue }) => ({
    ...obj,
    [name]: defaultValue ?? "",
  }),
  {}
);
```

---

As for removing selected options as you iterate through the fields, that's a little trickier.

You could use a memo hook to create an iterable data structure that includes the available options for that particular iteration.

For example

```js
const fieldsWithOptions = useMemo(() => {
  const taken = new Set(Object.values(select));
  const available = menuItemsValue.filter((item) => !taken.has(item));

  return fields.map((field) => ({
    ...field,
    options: select[field.name]
      ? [select[field.name], ...available] // include the current selection
      : available,
  }));
}, [menuItemsValue, select]);
```

Then map over `fieldsWithOptions` instead of `fields` and use `option.options` instead of `getMenuItems`.

Comment: That actually worked thank you so much ! What about the second part , where i have to check if date exists in sorterParam1 , exclude it from sorterParam2 and sorterParam3

Comment: @StivenBallshi no idea. Where does the list of available options come from?

Comment: The list of availabile items is coming form menuItemsValue, is basically a string[] , i'm getting that from the table columns names that's all , and showing them dynamically based on every different table and as you can see i'm passing that as a prop to SorterField which is where i have the 3 inputs there and render them there with Material UI , MenuItem component.

Comment: @StivenBallshi ah, I missed that initially. I've updated my answer with a slight change to your memo hook

Comment: It's actually working but there is a problem. When i select the value , the input is empty , it's totally blank. And the 'Date' which is default selected doesn't show anymore at all on any of the inputs

Comment: @StivenBallshi I had a feeling that might happen. I don't know these `SorterField` components you're using but you might want to separate the selected value from the available options if you intend on using them that way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249310/discussion-between-stiven-ballshi-and-phil).

Comment: @StivenBallshi answer updated, try that out

Comment: Oh i’m sorry it’s my mistake on the SorterField , as the name i put the option.title not option.name that’s why it was messing the state , but the only prob now is i can’t unselect Date from the first one because it has a default Value of Date